# How can I write to a remote file using Apache Commons Net?

Tags: java, ftp, remote-access, apache-commons

Once the program is connected to the server using the FTPClient connect() method, how can I send Strings and append them to a file located in the remote machine?

I have read other posts but they don't use Apache Commons Net library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#appendFile(java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream)) (you did check the docs, right?), you need the appendFile() method on the FTP client.

Something like

```
String text = "...."
String remoteFileName = "..."
FTPClient ftp = ... // Already connected

try (ByteArrayInputStream local = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.toBytes("UTF-8"))) {
    ftp.appendFile(remoteFilename, local);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Uh-oh", ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question arises, why putting "UTF-8" and what difference does it make? Thanks again.

Comment: "UTF-8" is the character set that the remote end will use when its appending your string. I picked it as a good default, but you'll want to check your local environment.